# PHP removes new line

Tags: php

When running this file:

```
works

fine
<?php echo 'except when it'; ?>

<?php echo 'does not'; ?>
```

I'd expect to see the following output:

```
works

fine
except when it

does not
```

Since there obviously are 2 newlines after the first echo statement, but instead it prints:

```
works

fine
except when it
does not
```

So php removes newline if there is nothing but php code on the line? Why does it happen?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php): "The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present."

Comment: @bux, huh, years of working with php but I never knew that - guess I never cared of what HTML looked like, thank you!

Comment: @Fluffy HTML would always require a new line to be explicitly said somehow, either by linebreak `<br>` or by block element like `<div>`. However, by templating with PHP, you would have hard time to structure your HTML to look good, if it was your point. Years of working with PHP, and the HTML was never well formatted

Comment: @RoyalBg, there's like 2 sites in the internet with HTML well formatted, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real comment the manual has about this is:

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php

Meaning, `?>\n` is taken as the block closing delimiter, and both are removed from the final output. I expect this is to remove unnecessary blank lines in code like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach (..) ?>
    <li>..</li>
```

However, it *does* make it hard to control output of newlines, and there's no elegant way to solve it:

- add an extra space after the closing tag (`?> \n`), which causes the newline to be output (but also the space)
- explicitly echo a newline character
- add an additional newline after the PHP block

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is quite painful when trying to achieve a nicely formatted HTML, such as

```
<label>
    <?= $label ?>
</label>
```

which, in this case, prints out as

```
<label>
    This is label    </label>
```

So there would have to be either an additional new line

```
<label>
    <?= $label ?>

</label>
```

which makes code uglier - or, you could "just" add a space after the tag, but that's silly. OK, it doesn't matter that much in HTML, but if you output a plan text or some structured data, it could just go wrong.

I have a funny feeling that in early days of PHP, there was a different closing tag for situations one wanted a new line, but I cannot find any references. It was something like

```
<?= $label /?>
```

But maybe it's just in my head?

Comment: Oh my god! You saved my ass! Adding a space to the end does make it retain nice formatting in the HTML source code!

Comment: OK, but then I would need to turn off my IDE setting to remove white space where it's not necessary.

Answer (score -2):

The PHP part itself does not output any newlines because you haven't given it any reason to do so.
You can explicitly output a newline by echoing `\n` like:

```
works

fine
<?php echo 'except when it\n'; ?>

<?php echo 'does not'; ?>
```

Should give the right result.
When the closing tag is followed by a `\n`, that `\n` will be read as a part of the closing tag, and removed from the output.