# Which "trailing newline" the PHP manual is talking about? It's just confusing the manual readers and PHP learners. Please clear the confusion

Tags: php, html, tags, newline, linefeed

I'm reading the PHP manual. I come across a sentence on the manual page(URL : [Instruction separation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)). There is the first paragraph on this page saying :

> As in C or Perl, PHP requires instructions to be terminated with a
>   semicolon at the end of each statement. The closing tag of a block of
>   PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a
>   semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block. **The closing tag
>   for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is
>   present.**

I understood everything written in the above paragraph except the last highlighted sentence i.e.

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing
>   newline if one is present.

**What does this sentence mean? What does this sentence imply?**

This sentence has created confusion and doubts in my mind.

- What exactly mean by "Trailing Newline" here?
- Is the meaning of **"Trailing Newline"**, **"Line feed"**, HTML escape sequence character `"\n"`, `<br>` same in this context? Or something else?
- What exactly does the "trailing newline" mean here? The newline present just before the closing PHP tag (`?>`) or the newline present just after the closing PHP tag (`?>`)
  ?

Someone please answer all of my questions in simple, lucid and easy to understand language. **It would be far better if you explain with some working code example demonstrating this concept.**

Note : I've referred the [already asked question on stackoverflow about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014115/what-does-it-mean-the-closing-tag-for-the-block-will-include-the-immediately-tr) but its answer is not satisfactory, it's incomplete and vague. So, please don't mark my question as Duplicate of [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45014115/what-does-it-mean-the-closing-tag-for-the-block-will-include-the-immediately-tr). Thanks.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27102974/661872

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: That answer is not so clear. It doesn't clear all the doubts I have. I need more in detail and precise answer to my doubts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it says that if you have `?>` in your code somewhere and then output on the next line, there won't be a newline/line feed/`\n` in the output there.

```
foo
<?php /* whatever */ ?>
bar
```

Will output

```
foo
bar
```

So even though there are three lines in the code, there are only two lines in the output.
Note that if you add a space after `?>` on that second line, there will be a line with just a space between `foo` and `bar`. That is what is meant with the "immediately" part of the docs.

To answer your specific questions:

> What exactly mean by "Trailing Newline" here?

It means the starting of a new line directly after the `?>` closing tag.

> Is the meaning of "Trailing Newline", "Line feed", HTML escape sequence character `"\n"`, `<br>` same in this context? Or something else?

The "trailing newline" is the newline/line feed/`\n` that "trails" (comes directly after) the `?>` closing tag. So newline, line feed and `\n` mean basically the same thing. It does *not* mean `<br>`.

> What exactly does the "trailing newline" mean here? The newline present just before the closing PHP tag (`?>`) or the newline present just after the closing PHP tag (`?>`) ?

The newline present just *after* the closing tag `?>`. This can be seen in my example, which has no newline *before* the `?>`.

> > **The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.**
>
> I understood everything written in the above paragraph except the last highlighted sentence i.e.

What is meant by this is: if a closing tag is followed directly by a newline, the newline is considered to actually be a part of that closing tag.
So my example above is parsed as:

1. `foo` -> output "foo"
2. `\n` -> output a newline
3. `<?php` -> start processing PHP
4. `/* whatever */`
5. `?>\n` -> stop processing PHP
6. `bar` -> output "bar"

Comment: If such is the case then it's contradicting with the statement from the manual. As mentioned in last sentence that the closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline(i.e. according to you is the newline/line feed/\n) if one is present. You are saying in your answer that the same trailing line(i.e. newline/line feed/\n) after the closing tag is not included, it will be removed by PHP closing tag ?> Please clear the confusion and modify your answer accordingly.

Comment: On the docs page you linked to, it says "The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.". I read that as "If there is a newline directly after the closing tag of a block, that newline is treated as part of the closing tag"; since the newline is 'part of' the closing tag, it doesn't end up in the output. Does that clear up your confusion?